# How to fix Docker error System.InvalidOperationException on start on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Docker desktop for windows 10 home (version 10.0.19042) but I was never able to make it work because I keep getting this error:
[image]

Microsoft.NET framework is the latest version.
When installing Docker I also let the box check to install all necessary WSL components.
This is the error message from Docker:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1
 stdout: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.


 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<ProvisionAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__29.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 194
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
```

This is the error from Microsoft.NET Framework:

```
    See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1
 stdout: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.


 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<ProvisionAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__29.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 194
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 69
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__20.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 109
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.TaskExtension.<Forget>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-16599\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Extensions.cs:line 30
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4420.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Docker Desktop
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.1.69879
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker%20Desktop.exe
----------------------------------------
Docker.Core
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.1.69879
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.Core.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.WPF
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.1.69879
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.WPF.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
Docker.ApiServices
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.1.69879
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.ApiServices.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.Engines
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.1.69879
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.Engines.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.HttpApi
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.1.69879
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.HttpApi.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4400.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Http
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26011.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Net.Http.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.NamedPipe
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.NamedPipe.DLL
----------------------------------------
NLog
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.5.10.8381
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/NLog.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Newtonsoft.Json
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.2.21924
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll
----------------------------------------
BITSReference5_0
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/BITSReference5_0.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.1
    Win32 Version: 4.6.28619.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Http
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Web.Http.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.Client
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.Client.DLL
----------------------------------------
netstandard
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/netstandard/v4.0_2.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51/netstandard.dll
----------------------------------------
Bugsnag
    Assembly Version: 2.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.2.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Bugsnag.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero2
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4420.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications
    Assembly Version: 1.5.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.5.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Runtime.DLL
----------------------------------------
Windows.UI
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.UI.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Foundation
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Foundation.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.Data
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Data.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.ValueTuple
    Assembly Version: 4.0.3.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26515.06
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.ValueTuple.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Collections
    Assembly Version: 4.0.11.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Collections.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
    Assembly Version: 4.0.4.1
    Win32 Version: 4.6.28619.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Owin
    Assembly Version: 4.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.81112.127
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
Owin
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.Server.Owin
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.Server.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
    Assembly Version: 4.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.1.81112.127
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Http.Owin
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Web.Http.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Http.Formatting
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL
----------------------------------------
SMDiagnostics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/SMDiagnostics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/SMDiagnostics.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationProvider
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationProvider/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationTypes
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4261.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.SqlXml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.SqlXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.SqlXml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel.Internals
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel.Internals/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.IdentityModel
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4250.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.IdentityModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Messaging
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Messaging/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Messaging.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.DurableInstancing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Services
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Services/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics.Vectors
    Assembly Version: 4.1.4.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26515.06
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Numerics.Vectors.DLL
----------------------------------------
Windows.Graphics
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Graphics.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.System
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.System.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Devices
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Devices.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Gaming
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Gaming.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.ApplicationModel
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Storage
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Storage.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Web
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Web.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Media
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Media.winmd
----------------------------------------
Windows.Security
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Security.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceProcess
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceProcess/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
SimCim.Core
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/SimCim.Core.DLL
----------------------------------------
SimCim.Root.V2
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/SimCim.Root.V2.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native/v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 4.1.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Runtime.Extensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
```

I scouted the internet around for hours but I found no solution to this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked if WSL2 subsystem is correctly installed? Check the [Docker WSL2 docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/). Update the question and add the text part of the error either from Error docker and the .NET Framework.

Comment: Added them, had to cut the last 1000 chars from the NET framework error log because it exceeded the 30k chars limit imposed by stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9586

it looks like some others had this problem

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to roberto.baboi's link I found the solution to fix my problem.
I had to run

> netsh winsock reset

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing this error happens because WSL2 in not installed properly on your machine try downloading it from the following [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package) and restart your machine it will work properly after that.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue persisted after trying other solutions. I dug a bit deeper and the solution [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/547#issuecomment-873540236) fixed my problem.

save this as a .reg file, install into registry, re-launch Docker Desktop

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\AppId_Catalog\0408F7A3]
"AppFullPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"
"PermittedLspCategories"=dword:80000000
```

More related links [here](https://jon.sprig.gs/blog/post/2140) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4177#issuecomment-597736482).