# Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1 || WslCommand.cs:line 146

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I have installed docker, then WSL2 package updated in win10. But I'm getting below error while running docker-desktop:-

```
 System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1
 stdout: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.


 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\4.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<ProvisionAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 179
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
```

[image: Error Snapshot]

These are my windows features enabled proofs:-
[image: Hyper-V disabled]

[image: Hyperversion plateform and WSL enabled]

Also enable WSL 2 as well and updated WSL package from microsoft website:-
[WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi)

Comment: I have Already tried uninstall docker, WSL 2 package as well as disabling windows feature and reinstalled again after a restart.

Comment: I also tried enabling Hyper-V as well, but still no luck.!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Docker error System.InvalidOperationException on start on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571532/how-to-fix-docker-error-system-invalidoperationexception-on-start-on-windows-10)